# How many different caches affect reputation count?

Tags: discussion, reputation, caching

I understand that reputation is cached and updated every once in a while, so I'm not surprised by seeing inconsistent values across different areas of the SE network.

However I was wondering how many different levels of caching affect reputation, so how many different values can we see at once.

For instance, I currently have three different values for my reputation for the [Italian Language proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42949/italian-language)

[image]

The above screenshot is taken from the Area 51 site.

You can see the flair showing 542, the site rep being 634, whereas my actual reputation on the site is 654.

My understanding is that there are at least three caches in place:

- the flair cache (which is apparently the most long-lived one)
- the Area 51 cache
- the actual site cache

How many other caches are there in place concerning the reputation count? What's the maximum number of different reputation values that can exist at once?

#### EDIT

I found a fourth one: the reputation on meta is shared with the one on the main site (with the notable exception of Meta StackOverflow), but it appears to be cached separately too. For instance right now I have:

- 664 on meta
- 724 on the main site
- 704 on the Area 51 proposal
- 664 on the flair (that fact that it matches the reputation on meta, it's a coincidence, since it's often not true)

Comment: You can also include [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LDJRq.png) in your post :P

Comment: @hjpotter92 yep now the flair count updated, but we still have 3 different reputation counts.

Comment: 10 that  I can think of, ignoring raw HTML caches...probably forgetting 20 more

Comment: I currently have different reputation on gaming.SE and gaming.meta.SE. And I managed to save proof (saved just one second apart): https://web.archive.org/web/20180130093718/https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/171580/fabian?tab=topactivity and https://web.archive.org/web/20180130093719/https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/171580/fabian?tab=topactivity